# Construct a single-valued function increasing arbitrarily quickly at a point $x=x_0$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Title says it all.

(How) can we construct a function (a regular function, perhaps?) whose first derivative is arbitrarily large at a point $x = x_0 < \infty$?

Comment: Maybe wrting an unbounded function then trying to integrating it? Hint: $\int \ln x dx =$ ... ?

Comment: $f(x)= (x-x_0)^{-1}$

Comment: @WW1 I'm looking for better behavior at $x=x_0$. That function (and it's derivative) are not even defined there.

Comment: @David D please specify "better behavior" - how can the derivative be both defined and arbitrarily large ?

Comment: $Cx$ for large enough $C$........  Or $((x-x_0)^2+C)^{-1}$ for some small $C$.

Comment: Or you could integrate$((x-x_0)^2+C)^{-1}$ to give an arc-tangent: $arctan((x-x_0)/\sqrt C)/\sqrt{C}$ for very small $C$. The logistic function and tanh would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=-(x-x_0) \, \ln |x-x_0|$, extended by continuity at $x_0$. Then, its derivative is $f'(x)=-\ln |x-x_0|-1$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x)=+\infty$.

As mentioned in the comments, the primitive of any convergent improper integral would do the job.